# Getting file size before downloading it using afnetworking

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, afnetworking, nsurl

I have a problem, I want to get the file size of my link that i put in my textfield and show it in label before starting the download.
I've done few things and i with `[operation.response expectedContentLength]`
i just get 0. my code in .m file is this :

```
    NSString *fileName = [self.linkTextBox.stringValue lastPathComponent];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.linkTextBox stringValue]]];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    NSLog(@"size :%lld", [operation.response expectedContentLength]);
    self.detailText.stringValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld", [operation.response expectedContentLength]];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];
      [operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
      NSLog(@"bytesRead: %lu, totalBytesRead: %lld, totalBytesExpectedToRead: %lld", (unsigned long)bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead);
}];
     [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation   *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", path);
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];

        [operation start];
```

Comment: ask webdeveloper to give you the size... you cannot get size without download

Comment: The expected length may be 0 because the server doesn't supply you with the Content-Length header. Check the HTTP response to see if it's available or not.

Comment: i get the total length when i start the download but its not available before start. my link length shows in other download manager but not mine

Answer (score 1):

You can send a `HEAD` request instead of a `GET` one, this will ask the server to send you only the headers for your request. Most servers support this and its the preferable method when you want to obtain some metadata info about the entity you're querying, without having to download it.

The `HEAD` request can be achieved by creating a `NSMutableURLRequest` and setting the `HTTPMethod` property, something like this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:anURL];
request.HTTPMethod = @"HEAD";
// the rest of the code
```

This assuming the server developer did his job and he is expecting `HEAD` requests and is populating the appropriate http header fields.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the thing now i don't get it the solution you provide is type of void and i really don't know how should i set my label to show the *request.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question, I assumed you don't want to download the file. @i_am_jorf's solution should better work for you, if, as he and the other stated, the `Content-Length` http header is correctly send by the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the length before you download, but you can get it as soon as you start to get a response.

You want to use [setDownloadProgressBlock:](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.5.4/Classes/AFURLConnectionOperation.html#//api/name/setDownloadProgressBlock:), which is a method on the super class of `AFHTTPRequestOperation` which is `AFURLConnectionOperation`.  The callback has three parameters, the third of which is `totalBytesExpectedToRead`.

```
[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
    if (totalBytesExpectedToRead > 0) {
        // Do stuff...
    }
}];
```

As others have noted, that value can be 0 if the server doesn't set the content-length header in the HTTP response, so please handle that case.